# Why is there no fluorescence background in CARS?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, microscopy

In CARS (coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering), the detected signal is blue-shifted with respect to the excitation - how does this mean that there is no fluorescence or that the fluorescence can be filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluorescence is mostly red-shifted with respect to the excitation wavelength, as part of the energy goes to excite molecular vibrations. However, the reverse process also happens: if a molecule was vibrationally excited before electronic excitation, it can contribute this energy to fluorescence, which in this case is blue-shifted (so-called *hot bands*).

The main advantage of CARS is not that the signal is blue-shifted, but that it is *coherent*. It behaves like a laser beam so a detector can be put far away from the measurements cell behind a pinhole that blocks most of the fluorescence.